# Invalid literal suffix in MSVC 2017

Tags: c++, user-defined-literals

I have the following code in a file called `Console.hpp`:

```
inline std::wstring operator "" _t(const char* s)
{
  std::wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
  std::wstring wide = converter.from_bytes(s);
  return console::typografix(wide);
}

inline std::wstring operator "" _t(const wchar_t* w, size_t _)
{
  return console::typografix(w);
}
```

Now, inside `Main.cpp`, I have an `#include "Console.hpp"` and am trying to use the suffix

```
"Like this"_t
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

> Error C3688   invalid literal suffix '_t'; literal operator or literal
>   operator template 'operator ""_t' not found

Can someone help me figure out what's going on?

Comment: haven't you forget to add `size_t _` parameter in your first overload?

Comment: @W.F. afaik it's required only for `wchar_t`, not for `char`

Comment: Overload without `size_t` is about numeric user-defined literals not the string ones...

Answer (score 0):

The reason why error C3688 occurs is that the `operator""_t` accepting `const char *` parameter also needs to accept `std::size_t` like

```cpp
inline std::wstring operator""_t(const char* s, std::size_t) {
    /* ... */
}
```

See [User-defined literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal):

> (Before C++20) the user-defined literal expression is treated as a function call `operator ""X (str, len)`, where `len` is the length of the string literal, excluding the terminating null character.

Since the compiler only finds a valid `operator""_t` that accepts `const wchar_t *`, it will not match the string literal "Like this" is for `const char *` type or `std::string` type and only match a wstring literal like `L"Like this"_t`.